# Read from a named pipe in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, named-pipes

I'm attempting to create a webpage (using JavaScript and HTML) that displays data gathered by another process. The page is written in HTML and hosted using Apache on a virtual machine, which I can access through a browser.

My problem lies in actually getting the data into the HTML page. I was previously reading from a text file, but the people I work for want a more elegant solution using interprocess communications, specifically, named pipes. I've been trying for two days to figure out how to read from a pipe into JavaScript and I've had absolutely no luck.

So my question is, is there a way to do this? If not, is there some sort of workaround I can use to achieve the same result?

Various details:

- The process generating data and the script within the webpage are running on the same machine.
- This whole setup is located on a virtual machine, if that makes any difference.
- The data is just a string, nothing fancy. I've got going into the pipe from a C program just fine, the JavaScript end is where the trouble has arisen.

Sorry for the long-winded question, and thank you so much for your help!

EDIT: A solution for animating a webpage using HTML5 and node.js would also be welcome. I am currently researching this as an alternative solution while waiting for a response.

Comment: Why not write the file out to a static JS/JSON file that can easily be consumed on the browser?

Comment: I think websockets (or even small webserver) could be a workaround, but of course you need to embed the server into the process providing data.

Comment: @Stan Embedding wouldn't be an issue, that's probably the direction I'm heading if I can't find a quicker way. Right now I'm kind of clinging to the hope that I can do it with minimal changes to my code but it's looking unlikely.

Diodeus, that would work, but my employer seems very intent on using a pipe or something of that nature (for now). Good suggestion though, I may very well come back to it.

Comment: Use a Node.js server and stream your named pipe into a BinaryJS stream to the client over web sockets.  http://binaryjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could spawn the process that is generating this data with node.js, assuming you can use stdin(0)/stdout(1) as the named pipes, and then use socket.io to stream the data to the client.

[socket.io](http://socket.io/get-started/)

[child_process.spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Comment: I thought of this, and it's the solution I've been moving toward. I'm just not entirely sure how I'd continue animating the canvas, would sockets provide a means for this?

Comment: Sockets would simply give you a means of streaming the data to the client. Your client side code would then have to manage the state of that canvas as it received more data.   Without knowing the exact nature of the data, I can't say for sure, but you may want to consider looking into D3.